# Retrieve Salesforce Objects

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I am problem with the below Ampscript, this is the first step of what we want to achieve but it is not working. We are getting blank email.

```
%%[
var @recordID, @Email, @carRecord
set @Email = EmailAddress
set @recordID = lookup("Cars_DE","RecordID","EmailAddress", @Email)

set @carRecord = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("cars__c","Model__c,Type__c, Name","Id", "=", @recordID)


Rowcount : %%=RowCount(@carRecord)=%%

]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

@ Rsuri try like this

```
%%[

var @recordID, @Email, @carRecord
set @Email = EmailAddress
set @recordID = lookuprows("Cars_DE","EmailAddress", @Email)

if rowcount(@recordID)>0 then
  Set @row = ROW(@recordID,1)
  Set @act = FIELD(@row,"RecordID")  
  set @carRecord = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("cars__c","Model__c,Type__c, Name","Id", "=",@act)
endif

]%%
Rowcount : %%=RowCount(@carRecord)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend utilizing [**output()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/?section=output) to validate your variable values.

```
%%[

var @recordID, @Email, @carRecord, @count
set @Email = EmailAddress /* i suspect this is the issue */

output(concat("<br>email: ", @email))

set @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")

output(concat("<br>email (from send context): ", @email))

set @recordID = lookuprows("Cars_DE","EmailAddress", @Email)
set @count = rowcount(@recordID)

output(concat("<br>count: ", @count))

if rowcount(@recordID) > 0 then

  Set @row = row(@recordID,1)
  Set @recordID = field(@row,"RecordID")
  output(concat("<br>recordID: ", @recordID))

  set @carRecord = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("cars__c","Model__c,Type__c, Name","Id", "=", @recordID)

endif

]%%
<br>Rowcount: %%=RowCount(@carRecord)=%%
```